# read folder structure from a text file and create the structure - java

Tags: java, readfile

I have text file with content like below list a folder structure:

```
/root1

    /folder1
        /file1
    /folder2
        /file1
    /folder3
        /file1
/root2

    /folder1
        /file1
    /folder2
        /file1
    /folder3
        /file1
```

Is there any better way to implement a java program for solving this kind of problem? Or I just have to read through each line in the file?

I am new to Java to not sure what better libraries are there for reading files in Java.

Thank you.

Comment: So the file content is the directory structure and you want to store the structure in the code or you want read files from a dir structure like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is quite a specific task, and so I don't know about any libraries that would do it for you out of the box. The main idea is that you want to keep note of the current ancestors of the processed line. You can do it with a stack. I wanted to find out if my algorithm actually works so I coded it up and it does work :) Hope it helps.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class DirStuctureReader {

  private static final int INDENTATION = 4;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Directory result = new DirStuctureReader().read(new File("testfile.txt"));
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  public Directory read(File file) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    Stack<Directory> directoryStack = new Stack<>();
    Directory root = new Directory("/"); // a root directory for everything
    directoryStack.add(root);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      processLine(scanner.nextLine(), directoryStack);
    }

    return root;
  }

  private void processLine(String line, Stack<Directory> directoryStack) {
    int nLeadingSpaces = getNumberOfLeadingSpaces(line);
    if (nLeadingSpaces == -1) return;
    int depth = nLeadingSpaces / INDENTATION;
    while (directoryStack.size() > depth + 1) {
      directoryStack.pop(); // discard elements from the stack when we are deep and jump up one or more levels
    }
    String dirName = line.substring(nLeadingSpaces + 1);
    Directory directory = new Directory(dirName);
    directoryStack.peek().getChildren().add(directory); // add the directory to the children of the proper parent dir
    directoryStack.push(directory);
  }

  private int getNumberOfLeadingSpaces(String line) {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
      if (line.charAt(i) != ' ') return i;
    }

    return -1;
  }

  public static class Directory {
    private List<Directory> children = new ArrayList<>();

    private final String name;

    public Directory(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public List<Directory> getChildren() {
      return children;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. That did help me a lot! I was also planning to use Scanner

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the directories and files, somehow finally you should add the absolutePaths as inputs. If you want to do it via a file, as you write above, I suggest you to store the abolutePath of one file in one line. For example: 
 root1/folder1/file1 
 root1/folder2/file2 
 root2/folder2/file3 
 In this case it is more efficient, quicker to read the paths in the programm from the file, I think. Then you can use mkdirs() and createNewFile(). 
 On the other hand you should also take into consideration the file separator of the operating system. If you want to add new path into the file programmatically you should use File.separator constant. (Or you should use the same separator if you write the data manually.)

Comment: I agree with your suggestion on the folder structure. So going ahead with it :)